# Struggling to resize an image within Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have developed a console-based adventure game for my Sixth Form Computing class, and now want to migrate it into Tkinter. The main reason for this is that I can make use of pictures, mainly ones from [game-icons.net](http://game-icons.net/).

So far so good, but the images are such high quality that they appear huge when I display them. Here is an example:

[image: Problem with image size]

The code works by using a `for` loop to iterate through a list of items that are in the current area (that the player is in). Here is the code:

```
if len(itemKeys) > 0:
    l = Label(lookWindow, text="Looking around, you see the following items....\n").pack()
    for x in range(0, len(itemKeys)):
        icon = PhotoImage(file=("icons\\" + itemKeys[x] + ".png"))
        l = Label(lookWindow, image=icon)
        l.photo = icon
        l.pack()
        l = Label(lookWindow, text=("" + itemKeys[x].title())).pack()
        l = Label(lookWindow, text=("   " + locations[position][2][itemKeys[x]][0] + "\n")).pack()

else:
    l = Label(lookWindow, text="There's nothing at this location....").pack()
```

The part saying `("icons\\" + itemKeys[x] + ".png")` simply goes into the `icons` folder in the game directory and strings together a file name, which in this case would result in "key.png" because the item we're currently looking at is a key.

Now, however, I want to resize the image. I've tried using PIL (which people say is deprecated but I managed to install just fine?) but so far no luck.

Any help appreciated.
Jake

EDIT:
The question has been marked as a duplicate, but I've already [tried to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066202/resizing-pictures-in-pil-in-tkinter), but the person who answered seems to open a file, save it as a ".ppm"(?) file and then display it, but when I try I get a huge error that says that I couldn't display a "PIL.Image.Image".

EDIT 2:
Changed it to this:

```
im_temp = PILImage.open(("icons\\" + itemKeys[x] + ".png")).resize((250,250), PILImage.ANTIALIAS)
photo = PhotoImage(file=im_temp)
label = Label(lookWindow, image=photo)
label.photo = photo
label.pack()
```

and now get this:

[image: edit 2]

Comment: The original PIL is no longer being maintained (and is incompatible with Python 3, IIRC). However, there is a fork of PIL called [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x) which is probably what you have installed. The `PhotoImage()` function in your code needs PIL/Pillow to function, so if your code works on Python 3 you can be assured that you have a working Pillow installation. :) You can use the Pillow `Image.resize` method to resize your images.

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm struggling to find where to add the `Image.resize` bit. It seems like what I want, but how would I adapt the code? I tried adding `.resize(0.5)` as a test onto the end of the line where I open the file, but I get told that a `PhotoImage object has no attribute resize`. Obviously it's because I need to be doing it to an `Image` object, but how?

Comment: You have to do it in stages, as shown in the accepted answer in the linked [duplicate target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066202/resizing-pictures-in-pil-in-tkinter).  First load the file as a PIL Image. Then resize it. Then convert the resized PIL Image to a PhotoImage. This will probably make more sense once you've looked at the PIL / Pillow docs I linked to in my previous comment. Those docs aren't fantastic, but you should at least get an overview of them to know what PIL can do.

Comment: @PM2Ring tried to adapt my code, see Edit 2 above.

Comment: If you've tried something without success, you need to say that you did so, and what you tried. The original question just explained your program, with a little note at the end of "how do I resize in PIL?". The duplicate target linked above explains how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of resizing those huge images on-the-fly, you could preprocess them before bunding them with your application. I took the 'key' and 'locked chest' images and placed them in a 'icons' subdirectory, then ran this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob

for infn in glob.glob("icons/*.png"):
    if "-small" in infn: continue
    outfn = infn.replace(".png", "-small.png")
    im = Image.open(infn)
    im.thumbnail((50, 50))
    im.save(outfn)
```

It created a 'key-small.png' and 'locked-chest-small.png', which you can use in your application instead of the original images.

Answer (score 2):

For python 2 you can do something like this, it should work for python 3 as well after small changes of import

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

file = 'plant001.png'

image = Image.open(file)

zoom = 0.5

#multiple image zise by zoom
pixels_x, pixels_y = tuple([int(zoom * x)  for x in image.size])

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((pixels_x, pixels_y))) # the one-liner I used in my app
label = Label(root, image=img)
label.image = img # this feels redundant but the image didn't show up without it in my app
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: We can extend zoom from 1-D to 2-D with the code change of `zoom = zX, zY` and `image.resize(tuple([x*y for (x,y) in zip([x for x in image.size], zoom)]))`