# Python Tkinter - Menu icon doesn't show

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu

I'm building a menu with tkinter but the icons don't show.
Can you help me?

```
mb=Menu(w)
w.config(menu=mb)
fm=Menu(mb,tearoff=0)
om=Menu(mb,tearoff=0)
hm=Menu(mb,tearoff=0)
mb.add_cascade(label=_("File"),menu=fm)
fm.add_command(label=_("Esci"), image=PhotoImage(r"icons\exit.png"),
               compound="left",command=w.destroy)
fm.iconPhotoImage = PhotoImage(r"icons\exit.png")
mb.add_cascade(label=_("Opzioni"),menu=om)
om.add_command(label=_("Impostazioni"), image=PhotoImage(r"icons\settings.png"),
               compound="left", command=settings.creaFinestra)
om.add_command(label=_("Cambia lingua"), image=PhotoImage(r"icons\language.png"),
               compound="left", command=settings.cambiaLingua)
mb.add_cascade(label=_("Aiuto"), menu=hm)
hm.add_command(label=_("Guida"), image=PhotoImage(r"icons\help1.png"),
               compound="left",
               command= lambda: webbrowser.open("https://github.com/maicol07/school_life_diary_pc/wiki"))
hm.add_command(label=_("Informazioni"), image=PhotoImage(r"icons\help.png"),
               compound="left",command=info)
```

Comment: Could you try and display one of the images in your main widget? Just add `Label(w, image=PhotoImage(r"icons\settings.png")).pack()` in your code. If it doesn't show up, then the problem lies in the image creation itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm), for such images formats, you need to use the [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) library which *converts them to Tkinter-compatible image objects*:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("icons\exit.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

Then attach it to your widget:

```
fm.add_command(label=_("Esci"), image=photo, ...)
```

You need to repeat this process for each .png image you used.

Comment: But I use images with the PhotoImage function also with other widgets... Note that I'm using Python 3.6.2

Comment: png is support in the current release of tkinter.

Comment: true, I do not know which version the OP is using, but since he is not displaying them, I suppose his version is not that new. @SierraMountainTech

Comment: I just noticed the OP commented he is using 3.6.2 and thought I would bring up that bit of info as it is relevant to the OPs question

Comment: In the same screen I have an other png image. In an another file I added three buttons each one with an image. The problem is that these image are not displayed... Now I'll share you the full code

Comment: Please test [this code](https://pastebin.com/u6DViT6L) and tell me if it works for you (you can change `hello.jpg` file with a PNG file) @MaicolBatti

Comment: I think that Tkinter doesn't support jpg images... this is the error:

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="369975.jpg")
  File "C:\Users\Maicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Maicol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "369975.jpg"`

Comment: The error says your Tkinter version does not support PNG files. So you have no option other than my own solution or upgrading your Python/tkinter versions to the current ones @MaicolBatti

Comment: No, I don&#39;t think that, I have a PNG image in the program in a Label and it displays well...

Comment: With the method in the answer I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maicol\Documents\Projects\App_WINDOWS\School_Life_Diary\main.py", line 100, in <module>
    image = Image.open("icons\exit.png")
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

Comment: For me it works ... use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748822/img-image-openfp-attributeerror-class-image-has-no-attribute-open) to fix that error. @MaicolBatti

Comment: Ok, now it works... but the icons are big!! Are there any method to scale them automaticly? Thanks

Comment: Resizing your icons is a classical problem. There are many posts about it on this website. For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066202/resizing-pictures-in-pil-in-tkinter) @MaicolBatti

Comment: I tried, but the image doesn't display... This is the code: `fm.add_command(label=_("Esci"),
               image=PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open("icons\exit.png").resize((32,32),PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)),
               compound="left",command=w.destroy)`

Comment: maybe you made them too small? Try to see if any errors were thrown in case you did not code the resizing correctly. Debug your code, nothing is difficult, you can handle that yourself if you want to be a programmer @MaicolBatti

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip. I think the best thing to do (because the icons are only for the menu) is resize them externally with paint.net. Thanks for your help! However, Python allows this method with PIL only if the images are in different variables... I don't know why... but it works!

Comment: EDIT: I have found the problem: the resize must be effettued in more variables. Like this: https://pastebin.com/ULAZfSJm