# Tkinter button image is blank

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I tried to create a button with an image, but the image gets very small and black.

I searched all over the internet for a solution, but it's still not working.

This is part of my code:

```
ph = tk.PhotoImage(file = "X.gif")
btn = tk.Button(master = back, command = game, height = 10, width = 20)
btn.config(image = ph)
btn.image = ph
btn.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

Comment: What size is the image you're using?

Comment: Try removing the height and width parameters. What do you get then?

Comment: @Moralous 500*500

Comment: @Miraj50 Now it's working, but I need to resize the image

Comment: If that is the case, you would have to use PIL, I guess. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066202/resizing-pictures-in-pil-in-tkinter).

Comment: @Daniel If you managed to solve the problem please reply to this question with your answer! https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by removing the height and width parameters in the Button constructor, and resizing the image.

Now the code is:

```
ph = tk.PhotoImage(file = "X.gif")
btn = tk.Button(master = back, command = game)
btn.config(image = ph)
btn.image = ph
btn.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
```

I understood that after defining the image, the width and the height are the size in pixels.